# Delete HDI cluster in Azure using Azure CLI 2.0

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-cli

I have created a HDI cluster and its associated storage account using Azure CLI 2.0 and ARM template.

Now I want to the delete the cluster using Azure CLI 2.0. But I don't find command option to delete it.

In Azure CLI 1.0 , I will delete a cluster using the following:-

```
azure hdinsight cluster delete <Cluster Name>
```

How can I delete a cluster using Azure CLi 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Azure CLI 2.0 does not support HDInsight clusters.

But if you only want to delete a HDI cluster, it is possible.  You could use like below:

```
az resource delete --ids /subscriptions/{subscription Id}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup Name}/providers/Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/{cluster name}?
```

In fact, Azure CLI 2.0 is using Azure rest API, you could use `--debug` to check it. You could check HID rest API in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/hdinsight/hdinsight-cluster#delete). You also could use `az resource create` to create a HDI cluster if you want.

Comment: I am using arm template to create using azure cli 2.0 for execution without using subscription id. So I want to delete HDI cluster using service principal credentiasl. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You could use Azure CLI to get current subscription id.

Comment: Use this command `az account show --query '{"subscriptionid": id}'
`

Comment: Yeah. It works. Is there way to get value of subscription using az command OR should I have to use jq command to get that value.

Comment: Yes, it is easy for you to do this, just like `az account show --query '{"subscriptionid": id}'|jq '.subscriptionid'`

Comment: Can you join to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166653/delete-hdi-cluster-using-az

Comment: Yes, I could. But it seems the room does not allow me chat.

Answer (score 1):

According to [azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-delete-cluster#azure-cli-10) -

> Azure CLI 2.0 does not support deleting HDInsight clusters at this
>   time (October 23, 2017).

Have you explored doing cluster creation and delete using powershell instead?